# Google advanced search with in specified sites

Tags: search, sites

How can I search with in two sites say for ex stackoverflow and msdn only to be searched in google advanced search?

Answer (score 1):

googling for 'sharepoint site:stackoverflow.com site:microsoft.com' (without the quotes) didn't work for me. nor with a comma seperated list for site:.  This is the same query that would be constructed using the Advanced Search page at google. So, I don't think it is possible, you'll have to run 2 seperate queries.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is it possible with other search like Bing as well.

Comment: @user420054 : I don't know. What happened when **you tried it?**. Did you know this site is focused on supplying answers to programming questions? You don't seem to know about APIs, or mention any method of automation (a programming language) that you are using, so I'm starting to think that you're not doing a programming project. There maybe associated sites with stackoverflow that answer user level questions as you post them, but I don't know them well enough to tell you which one to use. Good luck and keep searching!